# Choose 2 radio buttons on form

Tags: c#

I'm creating a program that allows the user to choose 2 different options, 1 for the dormitories and 1 for the meal plan. I'm using radio buttons for both, but I can only choose 1 button at a time, and I want to be able to choose both at the same time

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int totalCharge = 0;
        totalCharge = Dorm() + MealPlan();
        Form1 TChargeForm = new Form1();
        TChargeForm.label1.Text = totalCharge.ToString("c");
        TChargeForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
        radioButton3.Checked = false;
        radioButton4.Checked = false;
        radioButton5.Checked = false;
        radioButton6.Checked = false;
        radioButton7.Checked = false;
    }

    private int Dorm()
    {
        int total = 0;

        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            total += 1500;

            return total;
        }
        if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            total += 1600;

            return total;
        }
        if (radioButton3.Checked)
        {
            total += 1500;

            return total;
        }
        if (radioButton4.Checked)
        {
            total += 1500;

            return total;
        }
        else
        {
            return total;
        }


    }
    private int MealPlan()
    {
        int total = 0;

        if (radioButton5.Checked)
        {
            total += 600;
            return total;
        }
        if (radioButton6.Checked)
        {
            total += 1200;
            return total;
        }
        if (radioButton7.Checked)
        {
            total += 1700;
            return total;
        }
        else
        {
            return total;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Separate your two sets by `GroupBox`, that will automatically group radio  buttons into two sets and allows you to choose two options.

Comment: Why not just use two check boxes?

Comment: That tells you that Radio Buttons are the wrong choice here; they're used to get the user to pick one item out of many. To let the user choose zero to maximum items in a list, you use check boxes.

Comment: no I need radio buttons, The user picks one meal plan and one dormitory plan.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `GroupName` property for each type of button: dorimitories, mealplan

Answer (score 0):

Groupname attribute allows you to create logical groups of selections for radio buttons.

Add this attribute to every radio button or at the group box level.